# How to filter sparql query result with a pattern?

Tags: sparql, marklogic

When trying to filter a sparql result in MarkLogic with the following pattern,

```
SELECT ...
WHERE
{
    ...
    FILTER ( EXISTS { ?parent <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#broader>+ ?root } )
}
```

I get the following error:

```
[1.0-ml] XDMP-UNEXPECTED: (err:XPST0003) Unexpected token syntax error, unexpected {, expecting (
Stack Trace

At line 17 column 19:
In xxxx
17. FILTER ( EXISTS { ?parent <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#broader>+ ?root } )
```

Does MarkLogic not support Sparql 1.1 syntax or is my query incorrect?

I tried the following as well:

```
FILTER EXISTS { ?parent <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#broader>+ ?root }
```

And the error message is:

```
[1.0-ml] XDMP-UNEXPECTED: (err:XPST0003) Unexpected token syntax error, unexpected {, expecting (
```

Comment: Have you tried `FILTER EXISTS { ?parent <...>+ ?root }`? That's how it's used in examples in [http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/](documentation).

Comment: No, it does not work. I updated my question with the additional information.

Comment: Hm, it will probably be something specific to MarkLogic, works fine on Virtuoso.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is currently a request for enhancement for this specific case at MarkLogic.  An updated version of MarkLogic is forthcoming that has it corrected in it.  Contact your MarkLogic SE or AE, they can point you further to the timeframe and other information.

Comment: To elaborate a little, MarkLogic 8 supports SPARQL 1.1 only partially. Engineering is working on getting to full support.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex expression if you for specific patterns

Example if your query is something like this:

```
 SELECT ?subject ?term
 WHERE {
 ?subject <http://www.smartlogic.com/schemas/docinfo.rdf#tagged_with> ?term 
 FILTER regex(?term, "red", "i" )
 }
```

where "i" is for case insensitivity.